# What is the difference between "fine" and "good"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives

What is the difference between *fine* and *good*? Please suggest the proper usage.

Comment: Perhaps there is a specific usage that you are interested in?

Comment: _fine idea_ vs _good idea_

Comment: Related: [Why the word "fine" is often used as "just satisfying" instead of "very high quality"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/452956/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something that is *fine* is better than something that is merely *good*:

> **fine** 1. Of superior quality, skill, or appearance: *a fine day*; *a fine writer*.
>
> **good** 1. Being positive or desirable in nature; not bad or poor: *a good experience*; *good news from the hospital*.

As you see, *good* can simply mean "not bad"; but *fine* means superior, excellent.

See definitions [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fine) and [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/good).

Comment: For example, when describing the [condition of a (second-hand) book](http://www.ioba.org/desc.html), *fine*  is better than *very good* which is better than *good*.

Comment: Although both are often used ironically, e.g. Laurel and Hardy's "another fine mess".

Answer (score 11):

Robusto's answer is correct when they are being used attributively, to describe something in particular.

But in idiomatic usage on their own, there is really nothing to choose between them:

"That's fine" means the same as "That's good" or "That's OK".

"Fine" also has a subsidiary meaning of "healthy, well", so "I feel fine" is appropriate when somebody has expressed a concern about your health. "I feel good" would not be idiomatic there, at least in the UK.

Comment: Ironically "I feel good" has a stronger connotation, at least in my experience (US).  "I feel great" > "I feel good" > "I feel fine"

Comment: You hear "I am doing good" for instance here in the states all the time (where of course "doing well" or "doing fine" is more correct....)

Comment: I would take "fine" one step further and say it can actually be perceived as a negative response.  For example: "Hows the food?" - "It's fine." That's not taken well, but to say "It's good." is a real complement.  "That's fine" is also a common response from someone who is giving something up or on the short-end of a compromise: "You drive the kids all over the place and I'll watch TV, OK?" - "Fine."  It can go on and on (at least in the US)

Comment: So, it's confusing to me. Is `fine` better than `good`, or `good` better that `fine`?

Comment: @Roman: as an adjective preceding a noun, "fine" is rather rare (except in set expressions like "fine wine" and "fine arts"), so if it is used it is generally exceptional, and stronger than "good". As a predicate or adverb ("I'm fine", "I feel fine", "That's fine") it is no stronger than "good" and often weaker.

Comment: So `fine idea` is better than `good idea`?

Comment: @Roman: yes, I would say "a fine idea" is better - stands out more - than "a good idea".

Comment: @ColinFine: As an adjective, I think "fine" is often more descriptive of a category of things to which something belongs, rather than a description of an individual object.  Describing a bottle as a "fine wine" suggests that it is from a good maker and vintage; describing it as a "good wine" suggests that the liquid in the bottle has been tasted and found to be palatable.  As a predicate or adverb, "fine" has come to be accepted as meaning "not worth complaining about", even if the reason for not complaining has more to do with a fear of consequences than a lack of basis.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you're qualified to pass judgment on this matter?

Answer (score 0):

Supercat pointed out in a comment that

> As an adjective, I think "fine" is often more descriptive of a category of things to which something belongs, rather than a description of an individual object. Describing a bottle as a "fine wine" suggests that it is from a good maker and vintage; describing it as a "good wine" suggests that the liquid in the bottle has been tasted and found to be palatable.

> As a predicate or adverb, "fine" has come to be accepted as meaning "not worth complaining about", even if the reason for not complaining has more to do with a fear of consequences than a lack of basis.

Corey Coogan pointed out in a comment that

> "That's fine" is also a common response from someone who is giving something up or on the short-end of a compromise: "You drive the kids all over the place and I'll watch TV, OK?" - "Fine."

Answer (score -3):

Fine is the same as good! There is no difference! So if your teacher says your essay is fine, you should have 100 percent right to get an A+ on it!

Comment: There is some nuance of difference between them. _Fine_ can be used to mean _average_ in some contexts. If you suggest we do something and I say "Okay, fine," that doesn't necessarily mean I think it's a good idea; it just means I don't have any objections to it.