# Why the word "fine" is often used as "just satisfying" instead of "very high quality"?

Tags: adjectives, degree-of-comparison

The definition still says,

> of high quality.
>
> "this was a fine piece of filmmaking" · "fine wines"

But too many times, we see people using the word to describe a so-so state, like "I'm doing just fine in the exam."

I heard people say, "that restaurant is fine." Does it mean "just okay", "mediocre", "at least not bad", or "top-notched" like "fine dining"?

Comment: Please cite the source of the definition.

Comment: Is this question (1) asking how to distinguish the two different uses of the word, or is it (2) a request for a historical explanation of how the word came to be used in these two different ways? The body of the question points to (1), but its heading points to (2).

Comment: That you heard people say "that restaurant is fine" says what about their intent, please? I suggest it doesn't mean "just okay", "mediocre", "at least not bad" nor anything of the kind.

I think you're mixing up too many things. I think "fine" really means "of (very) good quality" but in every-day use "(very) good" is often subsumed into "acceptable." However, "acceptable" does not at all mean "just about acceptable…"

Answer (score 3):

> I heard people say, "that restaurant is fine." Does it mean "just okay", "mediocre", "at least not bad", or "top-notched" like "fine dining”?

There’s no way to tell for sure, although intonation will often provide some strong clues. For example, if I pointed out the car window and told you, “That restaurant is fine,” I probably wouldn’t say it in the same way if I meant, “top-notch, fine dining,” as I would if I meant, “sufficient or mediocre.” The former might be said more like an enthusiastic exclamation, while the latter might be said with a shrug or a resigned sigh.

Surrounding context also can reveal the intended meaning. As we walked down the street together, I can’t imagine saying, “That restaurant is fine,” without any additional information. For example, I might say:

- That restaurant is fine – I had dinner there a couple years ago. Best steak I ever had in my life!

Or, if you and I were looking for some place to eat, I might say:

- That restaurant is fine – I was hoping to find somewhere nicer, but this will do. I’m getting pretty hungry anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Fine has several meanings depending on context. My answer only addresses the OP's question. Not every single meaning of fine.

- That x is fine. [someone was criticizing something and another says the thing is fine, meaning; OK]
- I'm doing just fine. [that is similar to the usage above. It is often denotes an attitude: sarcasm, irony, relief etc.
- A fine restaurant = when used as an adjective, it means good or high quality.

These meanings are in most dictionaries. See definition 6 in [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fine?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld)

[note: topnotch]

Answer (score 0):

Fine [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fine) is usually an adjective, but in conversation you can also use it as an adverb. Fine has two main meanings that apply to the sense you seek:

1. used to mean 'very good'

You can use it to say that something is **very good or impressive**.

> From the top there is a fine view.

When you use fine like this, you can use words such as *very fine* or *extremely fine*.

You can't use fine as an adverb with this meaning, but you can use the adverb finely in front of an -ed participle.

> This is a finely crafted story.

2. used to mean '**satisfactory**'

You can also use fine to say that something is satisfactory or acceptable.

> 'Do you want more milk?' – 'No, this is fine.'